# Convert Text File From Unreadable Text to Readable Text

Tags: text, encryption, encoding

I'm trying to get this text file back to well readable text but I can't seem to find the encoding, it's for an Android application here is the one I'm trying to convert http://ge.tt/53SmHRP1/v/0

Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me a few tips on how to go about this as this is my first time with anything like this.

I've tried opening this with notepad, notepad++ & jedit to no avail the reason why I'm doing this is because I'm trying to create a cheat program for Plague Inc for Android but I can't seem to find the encoding for this file.

Comment: Why do you think it is a plaintext file to begin with?

Comment: Because before the update you could read the text and edit some of the values, but after the update it was changed, I've emailed the developers but for obvious reasons the aren't going to help me.

Comment: Which update? What are we talking about? It isn't any standard text encoding, so it's either corrupt or the update changed to a non-text format.

Comment: When the first brought out the game, you could read the text files that were used for the game, ever since they updated the game you can't yet the are still .txt files in the folder, 

unless I'm missing something they must still be text files, unless they are being made to look like text files and then read as something else because they aren't corrupted I pulled them from my device.

Comment: File ending is just a file ending.  It doesn't necessarily indicate content. Short of looking at the raw content in the file with hexedit or some similar tool, I don't believe there is a straightforward way to figure out what it is.

Comment: What if I decompile the apk back to source, do you think that might give out any (hopefully some) info?

Comment: Here is the java source decompiled from the smali to java http://ge.tt/api/1/files/2DmlfRP1/0/blob?download

Comment: Possibly. With that route, you can check for something like them encrypting the file which could be seen in the code.

Running [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) on that `.txt` file returns data so it is definitely not plaintext in its current state.

Comment: Ok thanks dan and here is the decompiled apk (apktool) http://ge.tt/2DmlfRP1/v/1 if that helps with this.